# Issues with refreshing kivy widgets

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having issues with refreshing a BoxLayout of widgets by removing them and then rebuilding the widgets based on the list 'Groups'. When on the EditDeviceGroups screen, the 'create' button should add an element to the list and forward the user to the GroupTemplateScreen, which it does.

The issue occurs when the user uses the back button to return to the EditDeviceGroups screen. At that point, I thought the on_enter method would refresh the widgets to include the new element, but the list shows no changes.

I assume it's some sort of issue with classes and instances, but I cant quite see around this one as this is my first real attempt with Kivy.

**soundclout.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button,Label
from kivy.graphics import Color,Rectangle,InstructionGroup

class GroupTemplateScreen(Screen):
    
    def remove(self):
        pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    skipBuild = 'build_timeline_screen_6'

    #skips build option if already timeline is already built
    def skip_build_screen(self,value):
        if value is 1:
            print('HomeScreen.skip_build_screen')
            self.skipBuild = 'edit_timeline_screen_7'

class EditDeviceGroupsScreen(Screen):
    #Groups = [GroupNo,null]
    Groups = [[1,10],[2,20]]

    def on_enter(self):
        self.ids.glayout2.clear_widgets()
        for i in xrange(0,len(EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups)):
            ##THISPRINT##
            print(str(EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups[i][0]))
            addedGroup = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None,height='120sp',orientation='horizontal')
            addedButton=Button(text="Group " + str(EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups[i][0]) + " Settings",font_size=25)
            addedGroup.add_widget(addedButton)
            self.ids.glayout2.add_widget(addedGroup)

    #Removes all widget on leaving to prevent the creation of duplicate widgets
    def nav_to_group(self):
        self.manager.current = 'edit_group_behaviour_screen_9'

    def create_group(self):
        base = 1
        for i in xrange(0,len(EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups)):
            if base < EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups[i][0]:
                base = EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups[i][0]
        EditDeviceGroupsScreen().Groups.append([base+1,(base+1)*10])        

#manages screens
class Manager(ScreenManager):

    home_screen = ObjectProperty()
    edit_device_groups_screen = ObjectProperty()
    group_template_screen= ObjectProperty()

    def update(self):
        self.connected_device_list._trigger_reset_populate()
        self.current_screen.update()

class SoundCloutApp(App):
    
    def build(self):
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())

if  __name__=='__main__':
    SoundCloutApp().run()
```

**soundclout.kv**

```
#: kivy 1.10.0
#: import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#: import main soundclout
#: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#: import ScrollView kivy.uix.scrollview


<GroupTemplateScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)
 
        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 20
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
           
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                orientation: "horizontal"
                height: 50
                spacing: 10
                padding: 0
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size   
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                    width:100
                    text: 'Back'
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'
       
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                    width:100
                    text: 'Remove'

                    #have to change first argument, for now assume switch is on
                    on_press: root.remove()
                    on_release:root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#ffffff')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                #Devices connected
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: hex('#98a6b3')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

                    Label:
                        text: 'Name:'
                        font_size: 24
                        
                        #TODO
                    Label:
                        text: 'Group 1'
                        font_size: 24

                #Devices connected
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: hex('#98a6b3')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

                    Label:
                        text: 'Devices:'
                        font_size: 24
                        
                    #TODO
                    Label:
                        text: '1,2,3,4'
                        font_size: 24

<HomeScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)
 
        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 50
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Button:
                text: "Start"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Device Tester"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Connect Devices"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Edit Device Groups"
                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'

            Button:
                text: "Edit Group Behavior"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Connected Devices"
                font_size: 30

<EditDeviceGroupsScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    #ToolBar
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)
 
        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 20
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50
                size: self.size
                text: 'create group'
                on_press: main.EditDeviceGroupsScreen().create_group()
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'group_template_screen_11'

            #Groups holder
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 5
                padding: 5
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#ffffff')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                #Adds Scrollability
                ScrollView:
                    do_scroll_x:False
                    do_scroll_Y:True
                    BoxLayout:
                        id: glayout2
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        spacing: 5
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    home_screen: home_screen
    edit_device_groups_screen: edit_device_groups_screen
    group_template_screen: group_template_screen

    HomeScreen:
        id: home_screen
        name: 'homescreen_1'
        manager: screen_manager

    EditDeviceGroupsScreen:
        id: edit_device_groups_screen
        name: 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'
        manager: screen_manager

    GroupTemplateScreen:
        id: group_template_screen
        name: 'group_template_screen_11'
        manager: screen_manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#Problem#
The *EditDeviceGroups* screen is not refreshed with the newly added widgets because when the *Back* button is pressed, another instance of *EditDeviceGroupScreen* was instantiated.

#Solution#
With the following changes, when the user clicked the *back* button to return to the EditDeviceGroups screen, the *on_enter* method refreshed the widgets to include the new element added. Please refer to the example and output for details.

##soundclout.kv##

1. Deleted ***#:import main soundclout***
2. Replaced ***main.EditDeviceGroupsScreen().create_group()*** with ***root.create_group()***

##soundclout.py##

1. Replace all occurrence of ***EditDeviceGroupsScreen().*** with ***self.***

#Example#
##main.py##

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.listview import ListItemButton
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, WipeTransition
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.button import Button, Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle, InstructionGroup


class GroupTemplateScreen(Screen):

    def remove(self):
        pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    skipBuild = 'build_timeline_screen_6'

    # skips build option if already timeline is already built
    def skip_build_screen(self, value):
        if value is 1:
            print('HomeScreen.skip_build_screen')
            self.skipBuild = 'edit_timeline_screen_7'


class EditDeviceGroupsScreen(Screen):
    # Groups = [GroupNo, null]
    Groups = [[1, 10], [2, 20]]

    def on_enter(self):
        print("EditDeviceGroupsScreen.on_enter:")
        self.ids.glayout2.clear_widgets()
        for i in range(0, len(self.Groups)):
            ##THISPRINT##
            print(str(self.Groups[i][0]))
            addedGroup = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=None, height='120sp', orientation='horizontal')
            addedButton = Button(text="Group " + str(self.Groups[i][0]) + " Settings", font_size=25)
            addedGroup.add_widget(addedButton)
            self.ids.glayout2.add_widget(addedGroup)

    # Removes all widget on leaving to prevent the creation of duplicate widgets
    def nav_to_group(self):
        self.manager.current = 'edit_group_behaviour_screen_9'

    def create_group(self):
        base = 1
        for i in range(0, len(self.Groups)):
            if base < self.Groups[i][0]:
                base = self.Groups[i][0]
        self.Groups.append([base+1, (base+1)*10])


# manages screens
class Manager(ScreenManager):

    home_screen = ObjectProperty()
    edit_device_groups_screen = ObjectProperty()
    group_template_screen= ObjectProperty()

    def update(self):
        self.connected_device_list._trigger_reset_populate()
        self.current_screen.update()


class SoundCloutApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Manager(transition=WipeTransition())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SoundCloutApp().run()
```

##soundclout.kv##

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import ScrollView kivy.uix.scrollview


<GroupTemplateScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)

        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 20
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                orientation: "horizontal"
                height: 50
                spacing: 10
                padding: 0
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Button:
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                    width:100
                    text: 'Back'
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'

                Button:
                    size_hint_x: None
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: 50
                    width:100
                    text: 'Remove'

                    #have to change first argument, for now assume switch is on
                    on_press: root.remove()
                    on_release:root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 10
                padding: 10
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#ffffff')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                #Devices connected
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: hex('#98a6b3')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

                    Label:
                        text: 'Name:'
                        font_size: 24

                        #TODO
                    Label:
                        text: 'Group 1'
                        font_size: 24

                #Devices connected
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    canvas:
                        Color:
                            rgba: hex('#98a6b3')
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

                    Label:
                        text: 'Devices:'
                        font_size: 24

                    #TODO
                    Label:
                        text: '1,2,3,4'
                        font_size: 24

<HomeScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)

        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 50
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Button:
                text: "Start"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Device Tester"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Connect Devices"
                font_size: 20

            Button:
                text: "Edit Device Groups"
                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'

            Button:
                text: "Edit Group Behavior"
                font_size: 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Label:
                text: "Connected Devices"
                font_size: 30

<EditDeviceGroupsScreen>:
    rows: 2
    spacing: 10
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    #ToolBar
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50
        spacing: 10
        pos: root.x, (root.height-50)

        # Make the background for the toolbar blue
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#0099cc')
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        Button:
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'homescreen_1'
            background_normal: 'icons/home.png'
            size_hint_x: None
            width:50

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 500
        spacing: 50
        padding: 20
        pos: root.x, (root.height-560)

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            padding: 10
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#0099cc')
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                size_hint_x: None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: 50
                size: self.size
                text: 'create group'
                on_press: root.create_group()
                on_release: root.manager.current = 'group_template_screen_11'

            #Groups holder
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "vertical"
                spacing: 5
                padding: 5
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: hex('#ffffff')
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                #Adds Scrollability
                ScrollView:
                    do_scroll_x:False
                    do_scroll_Y:True
                    BoxLayout:
                        id: glayout2
                        orientation: 'vertical'
                        spacing: 5
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height


<Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    home_screen: home_screen
    edit_device_groups_screen: edit_device_groups_screen
    group_template_screen: group_template_screen

    HomeScreen:
        id: home_screen
        name: 'homescreen_1'
        manager: screen_manager

    EditDeviceGroupsScreen:
        id: edit_device_groups_screen
        name: 'edit_device_groups_screen_5'
        manager: screen_manager

    GroupTemplateScreen:
        id: group_template_screen
        name: 'group_template_screen_11'
        manager: screen_manager
```

#Output#
[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Clicked Button EditDeviceGroups]
[image: Img03 - Clicked Button CreateGroup]
[image: Img04 - Clicked Button Back]